# GhostDoc element ordering / customization

Tags: c#, ghostdoc

How can I customize GhostDoc to do the following?

```
///<author>Moo</author>
///<summary>
/// Gets the user by ID.
///</summary>
///<param name=”ID”>The ID.</param>
///<returns></returns>
///<datetime>12/4/2012-11:23 AM</datetime>
```

Basically I want to prepend the author at the beginning of the comment and append the datetime at the end of the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the Pro version of GhostDoc but not in the free one.